# Strong mathematical induction without basis step

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm reading about strong mathematical induction in Susanna Epp's Discrete Mathematics, and here's the principle as it's stated in the textbook:

> 1. P(a), P(a + 1), . . . , and P(b) are all true. (basis step)
> 2. For any integer k ≥ b, if P(i) is true for all integers i from a through k, then P(k + 1) is true. (inductive step)

The principle is followed by the text that's confusing me:

> Strictly speaking, the principle of strong mathematical induction can
> be written without a basis step if the inductive step is changed to
> “∀k ≥ a − 1, if P(i) is true for all integers i from a through k,
> then P(k + 1) is true.” The reason for this is that the statement “P(i
> ) is true for all integers i from a through k” is vacuously true for k
> = a−1. Hence, if the implication in the inductive step is true, then the conclusion P(a) must also be true,∗ which proves the basis step
>
> ∗If you have proved that a certain if-then statement is true and if you also know that the hypothesis
> is true, then the conclusion must be true.

I understand why $k = a − 1$ makes the statement $\forall i \in Z ((a \leq i \leq k) \land P(i)) $ vacuously true, but can't grasp why replacing $k \geq b$ (and hence $k \geq a$ since $b \geq a$) to $k \geq a-1$ proves the basis step implicitly. Why is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the statements $ P(a), ..., P(a-1) $ are all true, since there are no statements in this list.  The author is using a somewhat confusing but common convention with ellipses: when you list $ firstElement ... lastElement $ where $lastElement$ precedes $firstElement$, you interpret that as an empty list.  I will add, the author should have written the basis step as "for all $i$ with $a \leq i \leq b $, $P(i)$ is true," so that the interval of integers was more clear.

Comment: okay I think I get it. P(a) is true as the conclusion of the implication because the hypothesis P(a-1) is true by default and we'll yet show that the implication is true. The conclusion of a true implication with a true hypothesis is true. Now that we know that P(a) is true, P(a+1) will be also true for the same reasons and so the inductive step "for all  with ≤≤, () is true" is proven. So k=a-1 is only needed as a hypothesis that we know is true.